# Compile error in java :cannot find symbol.

Tags: java, variables, input, compiler-errors

I have this code that is taking a text file and turning it into a string and then separating parts of the string into different elements of an arraylist.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Grocery{

    public Grocery(){

        File inFile = new File ("lists.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (inFile);
        String grocery;
        {
             grocery = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void makeSmallerLists(){
        String listLine;
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> smallList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(input.hasNextLine()){
            line = input.nextLine;
            if(line.equals("<END>")){
                smallList.add(listLine);
            } else{
                listLine = listLine + "\n" + line;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to compile this it gives me two errors:

> javac Message.java Message.java:31: cannot find symbol symbol  :
>   variable input location: class Message    while(input.hasNextLine()){
>           ^ Message.java:32: cannot find symbol symbol  : variable input location: class Message        line = input.nextLine;
>                ^

How do I fix this? I really don't know what's wrong.

I fixed that and now my error says
$ javac Message.java
Message.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable nextLine
location: class java.util.Scanner
        line = input.nextLine;
                    ^

```
           ^
```

Now what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner (inFile);
```

`input` is local to the constructor, you cannot access outside of it, and you are trying to access in  `makeSmallerLists()`  method.  Make it as a instance member, So that it available  through out the `class` other than `static` context.

```
public class Grocery{

  Scanner input;
```

and in constructor

```
public Grocery(){

            File inFile = new File ("lists.txt");
             input = new Scanner (inFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have variable scope problem. You can't get access a field outside of scope. Declare Scanner as globally, outside of costructor.

```
 public class Grocery{
    Scanner input = null;// Declare Scanner here.

    public Grocery(){
        .....
        input=new Scanner (inFile);
    }
```

Also append method bracket `()`.

```
      public void makeSmallerLists(){
       ......
        while(input.hasNextLine()){
        line = input.nextLine();// Append () after method. 
       .....
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the Scanner object `input` has been declared inside your constructor(local scope of the constructor) and thus its not visible in your `makeSmallerLists()`. You need to declare it as an instance variable so that it would be accessible in all the methods of the class.

```
public class Grocery {
    Scanner input; // declared here, as an instance variable
    public Grocery(){
        File inFile = new File ("lists.txt");
        input = new Scanner (inFile);  // initialized here
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void makeSmallerLists() {
        ...
        while(input.hasNextLine()) { // accessible everywhere within the class
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to have a [class member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) of type `Scanner`:

```
private Scanner input;
```

And in the constructor, construct it:

```
public class Grocery { 
   private Scanner input;

   public Grocery() {
      ...
      ...
      input = new Scanner (inFile);
   }
   ...
}
```

Now `input` is not limited to the *scope* of the constructor, it'll be accessible through the whole class.

---

Consider this example:

```
public class Example {
    int n = 0;  //n known everywhere in the class

    if(n == 0) {
       int n1 = 1;
       if(n1 == 1) {
          int n2 = 2;
          //n1 is known here
       }
       //n2 is not known here
    } 
    //n1 is not known here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` is not accesible outside the constructor...it's declared insisde the constructor